Mocking electron store with vitest
I have some code that I would like to mock with vitest, but for some reason I always get an error. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.
In theory, I think that I am mocking the module correctly but for the looks of the error that is not the case. I have debug it a couple of times and I always have the real object and never the mock.
This is the link to the external library that I am using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-store
Here is a simplified version of the code in file storage2.ts:
import Store from 'electron-store'

const store = new Store()

export const retrievePreferences = () => {
  return {
    url: store.get('url')
  }
}

export const savePreferences = (preferences) => {
  store.set('url', preferences.url)
}

This is the test and what I have tried so far in file storage2.test.ts:
import { vi } from 'vitest'
import Store from 'electron-store'
import { retrievePreferences } from './storage2'

// Try 1
// vi.mock('electron-store', async (importOriginal) => {
//   const mod = await importOriginal<typeof import('electron-store')>()
//   return {
//     ...mod,
//     Store: vi.fn()
//   }
// })

//Try 2 & 3
vi.mock('electron-store', async (importOriginal) => {
  const mod = await importOriginal<typeof import('electron-store')>()
  return {
    ...mod,
    Store: {
      get: vi.fn()
    }
  }
})

describe('storage', () => {

  test('retrievePreferences', () => {

    // Try 1
    // TypeError: vi.mocked(...).mockReturnValue is not a function
    // vi.mocked(Store.prototype.get).mockReturnValue('http://localhost')

    // Try 2
    // TypeError: vi.mocked(...).mockImplementation is not a function
    // vi.mocked(Store).mockImplementation(() => {
    //   return {
    //     get: 'http://localhost'
    //   }
    // })

    // Try 3
    // TypeError: vi.mocked(...).mockReturnValue is not a function
    const mockedStore = new Store()
    vi.mocked(mockedStore.get).mockReturnValue('http://localhost')

    
    const actual = retrievePreferences()

    expect(actual).toEqual({ url: 'http://localhost' })
  })
})

